# extracting element and insert a space

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

im parsing html using BeautifulSoup in python

i dont know how to insert a space when extracting text element

this is the code:

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<html>this<b>is</b>example</html>')
print soup.text
```

then output is

> thisisexample

but i want to insert a space to this like

> yes is example

how do i insert a space?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `getText` instead:

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<html>this<b>is</b>example</html>')

print soup.getText(separator=u' ')
# u'this is example'
```

Comment: this is `soup.get_text(separator=' ')` in more recent version of bs4 / python3, but passing a separator keyword argument works in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

If your version of Beautifulsoup does not have `getText` then you could do this:

```
In [26]: ' '.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
Out[26]: u'this is example'
```

Answer (score 2):

One may want to use also with strip argument

```
bs = BeautifulSoup("<html>this<b>is  </b>example</html>")
print(bs.get_text())  # thisis  example
print(bs.get_text(separator=" "))  # this is   example
print(bs.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True))  # this is example
```