# Python crawl : select text from <em></em>

Tags: python, select

I have a problem with learning python crawl as follow:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.zhipin.com/job_detail/1411924978.html'

result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text,'lxml').select('#main > div.job-banner > div > div > div.info-company > p')

print(soup[1])

print(soup[1].get_text())
```

the result is :

```
<p>IT软件<em class="vline"></em>已上市<em class="vline"></em>10000人以上</p>

IT软件已上市10000人以上
```

But what I want `print(soup[1].get_text())` is like this :

`IT软件 已上市 10000人以上`

or

```
IT软件
已上市
10000人以上
```

How can I to write the codes?

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
print soup[1].getText(separator=u' ') # space separator
print soup[1].getText(separator=u'\n') # newline separator
```

The output is:

```
>>> print soup[1].getText(separator=u' ')
IT软件 已上市 10000人以上
>>> print soup[1].getText(separator=u'\n')
IT软件
已上市
10000人以上
```

Source: [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6467095/6381085) => Please research your problem before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks thanks so much ~ really , I have got your advance , thanks a lot !

Comment: Sorry about that , this is my first time to use stackoverflow, thanks a lot again~Having a good day ~~